# Javascript Private Methods

Tags: javascript, private-methods

I was reading chapter 2 of Apres Javascript Pro techniques and in particular the section about **Provate Methods**.

The following code snippet is shown as an example:

```
// Listing 2-23. Example of a Private Method Only Usable by the Constructor Function
function Classroom(students, teacher) {
    // A private method for displaying all the students in the class
    function disp() {
       alert(this.names.join(", "));  // i think here there is an error. Should be alert(this.students.join(", "));
    }

    // Store the class data as public object properties
    this.students = students;
    this.teacher  = teacher;

    disp();
}
```

Apart the error at line 4, when i create a new Classroom object,

```
var class = new Classroom(["Jhon", "Bob"], "Mr. Smith");
```

the following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'join' of undefined.
```

Reading at douglas.crockford.com/private.html, I found this:

> By convention, we make a private that variable. This is used to make the object available to the private methods. This is a workaround for an error in the ECMAScript Language Specification which causes this to be set incorrectly for inner functions.

Indeed creating a **that** variable pointing to **this**, the previous code work as expected.

```
function Classroom(students, teacher) {
    var that;
    // A private method used for displaying al the students in the class
    function disp() {
        alert(that.students.join(", "));
    }

    // Store the class data as public object properties
    [...]   
    that = this;

    disp();             
}
```

So my question is:

- It is always necessary to  create a that variable?

If yes, this means that the example was definitively wrong.

Comment: If those errors are in Chapter 2, I dread to see the code examples in the later chapters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only necessary to store the value of `this` into another variable `that` if you for some reason want to keep the value that `this` had when calling the outer method.

The error you get (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'join' of undefined.) means that the property `names` was not found on the `this` object and that the value is therefore `undefined` and consequently cannot have a `names` property.

The value of `this` in JavaScript is a little complicated to know. If you invoke a function `f` as a **method**, that is if you write `o.f()` then `this` is bound to `o` inside the function `f`. If you call `f` as a **function**, that is `f()` then `this` is bound to the global (window) object (!).

Therefore, if you change the last line `disp();` to `this.disp();`, then `this` will be what you expect inside `disp`.

The code is indeed wrong...

Comment: I don't think that will work. In the example code disp isn't a member of Classroom so this.disp() will throw an error

Comment: That is correct. Disp would also have to be a member of classroom. That code is wrong in so many ways... :-)

Answer (score 2):

this refers to the owner of a function (window object, HTML element...) so in a private function you won't be able to access the object you're working on. so you store the object in `that` variable, so you can access it from any private method in the class.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example has another error in that you're not defining this.names, but the answer to your question is basically 'yes' - inside the disp function body the 'this' variable is assigned to the global scope, so you need to create the 'that' variable.